# Redux Toolkit's createAsyncThunk never dispatches rejected action

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit's `createAsyncThunk` and `Axios` for async requests.
Seems like rejected action is never dispatched, even though I type in an obviously wrong URL (should return a 404) as endpoint. I know there are a lot of questions related to this in StackOverflow, but there must be something that I just can't grasp because I've not been able to solve this problem for hours.

This is my Redux slice file:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const name = "listings";
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null
};

export const fetchListings = createAsyncThunk(
  "listings/requestStatus",
  async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet"
      //"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"
    );
    return response.data;
  }
);

const slice = createSlice({
  name,
  initialState,
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchListings.pending, (state) => {
      console.log("pending");
      state.data = [];
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchListings.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      console.log("fulfilled");
      state.data = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchListings.rejected, (state, action) => {
      console.error("rejected");
      state.data = [];
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.error.message;
    });
  }
});

export const selectListings = (state) => ({
  data: state[name].data,
  loading: state[name].loading,
  error: state[name].error
});
export default slice.reducer;
```

I tryed to try/catch the Axios call and to use `rejectWithValue` helper, but nothing seems to change. This is a [codesandbox to replicate the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-hodgkin-ig1iz). Redux slice is located in `store/listings` and causes the component `src/Listings` to fail.

If you remove the lorem-ipsum... wrong uri and uncomment the jsonplaceholder endpoint, you can easily see that everything is working fine. The wrong uri was used on purpose to trigger a 404 error and get a dispatched reject action, that unfortunately is not happening at all.

Comment: Error in sandbox: `listings.map is not a function`. The thunk is resolving and the `action.payload` isn't an array.

Comment: @DrewReese exactly, in fact the sandbox was created to replicate the problem. If there were no errors there would be no problem to solve 

Comment: Well, the error in the sandbox is completely unrelated you what you say is the issue here. If you are providing a ***running*** code sandbox that reproduces the issue it should (1) actually run, and (2) reproduce the issue. What debugging have you done already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a problem with your testing url.

I fork here: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-napier-6s51m

Using a service that guarantees a 404 response all seems working: https://mock.codes/404

So, fetchListings.rejected case is executed.

Comment: why is the payload of rejected requests undefined?

https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-leaf-4sxwmw